# h:commandButton not fired when using h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2

I've already checked BalusC suggestions on [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value/2120183#2120183), But i can't get my commandButton to get fired whenever i add a selectOneMenu dropdownlist

Here is my form:

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 template="/template/template.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="content">
  <h:form>
   <h:messages />
   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="Cin" />
    <h:inputText value="#{addEmployeeBean.cin}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Nom" />
    <h:inputText value="#{addEmployeeBean.nom}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Prenom" />
    <h:inputText value="#{addEmployeeBean.prenom}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Login" />
    <h:inputText value="#{addEmployeeBean.login}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Password" />
    <h:inputSecret value="#{addEmployeeBean.password}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Id_Contrat" />
    <h:inputText value="#{addEmployeeBean.idContrat}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Salaire" />
    <h:inputText value="#{addEmployeeBean.salaire}" />

    <h:outputLabel value="laboratoire:" />

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{addEmployeeBean.laboSelectionne}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{addEmployeeBean.labos}" var="lab"
      itemLabel="#{lab.nom}" itemValue="lab">
     </f:selectItems>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:commandButton action="#{addEmployeeBean.ajouterEmploye()}"
     value="Ajouter" />

   </h:panelGrid>
  </h:form>

 </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

And here is my managed bean:

```html
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AddEmployeeBean {

 private String cin;
 private String nom;
 private String prenom;
 private String login;
 private String password;
 private int idContrat;
 private float salaire;
 private List<Labo> labos;
 private Labo laboSelectionne;


 @EJB
 GererLaboServiceLabo gererLaboServiceLocal;
 
 @EJB
 GererEmployeeServiceLocal employeeServiceLocal;

 @PostConstruct
 public void init(){
  labos= gererLaboServiceLocal.listLabo();
  laboSelectionne = new Labo();
  
 }
 
 public String ajouterEmploye() {
  Employe employe = new Employe();
  Contrat contrat = new Contrat();
  contrat.setId(idContrat);
  contrat.setSalaire(salaire);
  employe.setCin(cin);
  employe.setContrat(contrat);
  employe.setLogin(login);
  employe.setNom(nom);
  employe.setPassword(password);
  employe.setPrenom(prenom);
  System.out.println(laboSelectionne.getNom());
  employe.setLabo(laboSelectionne);
  employeeServiceLocal.creerEmployee(employe);
  return null;
 }
```

Comment: Check your `f:selectItems` `itemValue` attribute. You have it set to a string literal. Outside of that are you getting anything in your logs or any FacesMessages?

Comment: You are right itemValue should be set to #{lab} which i did but i didn't change a thing. I'm not getting anything in the server's log neither any FacesMessages....

Comment: Do you have a converter registered for the `selectOneMenu`?

Comment: No i don't have any converter

Answer (score 0):

Your application isn't making it past the Apply Request Values Phase because of a conversion error. You need to convert the string `#{lab}` back into a `Labo` instance. JSF is only capable of doing implicit conversion for primitive, primitive wrappers, BigDecimal, and BigInteger. For everything else you have to create a custom converter (or make use of one of the `<f:convert.../>` tags provided by jsf).

Normally in these cases I will put all the selectable objects in a `HashMap` keyed by their database Id. So instead of `private List<Labo> labos;` you will have `private HashMap<String, Labo> labos;` where String is the unique ID. Now your `getLabos` will be

```
public Collection<Labo> getLabos(){
    return labos.values();
}
```

Assuming `Labo` has a field `id` for the primary key, `<f:selectItems...` becomes

```
<f:selectItems value="#{addEmployeeBean.labos}" var="lab" itemLabel="#{lab.nom}" 
    itemValue="#{lab.id}"/>
```

Now you can create a converter that will map the `String` value submitted with the form into a `Labo` instance. For this example I just created a public method that returns an anonymous instance of `Converter`; this would go in your `ManagedBean`.

```
    public Converter getConverter(){
        return new Converter(){
            @Override
            public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {              
                return labos.get(value);
            }
            @Override
            public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {  
                if(value instanceof Labo){
                    return ((Labo)value).getKey();
                }
                return value == null ? null : value.toString();
            }
        };
    }
```

Finally you can register the converter on your `selectOneMenu` tag

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{addEmployeeBean.laboSelectionne}" 
    converter="#{addEmployeeBean.getConverter()">
```

With all that said, it can also be simpler to just use Strings in your `selectOneMenu` and then when you go to set the Lab just look it up in your `HashMap`

```
employe.setLabo(labos.get(laboSelectionne));
```